# Change leading and trailing constraints for a UILabel in a TableView cell (Chat bubbles)

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to rebuild a TableView which should look like a chat. "My" chat bubbles should be on the right, the other users chat bubbles should be on the left.

So far everything works as intended for automatically resizing, and now I am trying to implement the left / right bubble.

These are my constraints:

[image]

Here is something I tried out, but my feeling here is totally wrong and obviously the code is not working:

```
var isIncoming: Bool! {
    didSet {
        labelChatMessage.backgroundColor = isIncoming ? .systemBlue : .darkGray

        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: labelChatMessage!,
                attribute: .leading,
                relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                toItem: superview,
                attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 28
        )

        let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: labelChatMessage!,
                attribute: .trailing,
                relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: superview,
                attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 8
        )

        if isIncoming {
        constraintMessageLeft.isActive = false
        constraintMessageRight.isActive = false
        leftConstraint.isActive = true
        rightConstraint.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change (swap values) my existing storyboard constraints?

Comment: why not create two cells. one for incoming and one for outgoing.